# Should an application stack consist of a single or multiple swarm clusters?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, magento2, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I'm in the process of building a Docker Swarm for a Magento application stack. The main reason to use Swarm is that the application stack will run in a multi-node environment.

Below are the services that the application stack would run -

1. Varnish (Accelerator)
2. Nginx (web server)
3. Redis (Caching / sessions)
4. MySQL (storage)

Should each of the above 4 services be a part of separate swarm clusters (i.e. 4 different swarm clusters)? Or, should there just be a single swarm cluster for the entire app stack along with some sort of a mechanism (possibly using Swarm filters), to deploy services to specific set of nodes only?

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

> Should each of the above 4 services be a part of separate swarm clusters (i.e. 4 different swarm clusters)?

Same swarm cluster (for all the service to access the same docker network), especially when using swarm mode.
See "[Deploy a multi services application with swarm mode](http://lucjuggery.com/blog/?p=604)" from Docker captain [Luc Juggery](https://twitter.com/lucjuggery).
He creates a docker network and a kv store (not needed when using swarm mode), and launch 4 services all attached to the same network.

```
docker-machine ssh manager1 docker network create -d overlay appnet
docker-machine ssh manager1 docker service create --name redis --network appnet redis:3.0.7-alpine
docker-machine ssh manager1 docker service create --name mongo --network appnet mongo:3.2
...
```

But the "swarm mode" fashion to group those service (again, in the same swarm cluster) is through [Distributed Application Bundle](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/), illustrated in "[My first try with DAB (aka Distributed Application Bundle)](http://lucjuggery.com/blog/?p=632)".
It uses [`docker-compose bundle`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/#/producing-a-bundle) to convert an existing docker compose file into a dab.
Note: bundles are still experimental in docker 1.12.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those links. Swarm service and bundle looks promising in terms of automating stuff. But, I have a question - If all my nodes are part of a single swarm, how can I control which service is deployed to which node? Example - MySQL service should only go to the DB nodes.

Comment: You should be able to define the affinity in the environment section (at least this was the way in the version 2 files, it may have changed, so consult the documentation on hot wo configure the affinity for your config file version)

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen I don't see affinity:container anymore in current version of docker though.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/6kvx1t/container_dependence_in_swarm/ See the answer of Relza